# Render a partial inside ActiveAdmin edit page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I need to render a partial inside ActiveAdmin page. I am trying something like:

```
  form(:html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
    f.inputs "Описание товара #{f.object.name if f.object.name}" do
      f.input :name, :required => true
      f.input :brand
      f.input :category
      f.input :created_at, :wrapper_html => { :class => 'inline-list' }
      f.input :updated_at, :wrapper_html => { :class => 'inline-list' }

      f.actions
    end
    content do
      render partial: 'fancybox'
    end
  end
```

But it doesn't work. My partial contents replace the form contents. I guess I need a right wrapper element for `render` but using `panel` was no success. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try to use `render` with `f.template`:

```
form(:html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
  f.inputs "Описание товара #{f.object.name if f.object.name}" do
    f.input :name, :required => true
    f.input :brand
    f.input :category
    f.input :created_at, :wrapper_html => { :class => 'inline-list' }
    f.input :updated_at, :wrapper_html => { :class => 'inline-list' }

    f.actions
  end
  f.inputs "Fancybox" do
    f.template.render partial: 'fancybox'
  end
end
```

Comment: BTW, if you are trying this with nested forms, use the innermost form builder

Answer (score 2):

You can also go with following

f.render partial: 'folder/partial page'      unless f.object.new_record?